# How to search a song on YouTube and get the first video ID

Tags: vb.net, winforms, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/search) and using the endpoint [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) I want to get the ID of the first video searched by a title. YouTube gives some code samples and this is one in c# that I'm trying to make it work in vb.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
 /// <summary>
 /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: search by keyword.
 /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
 /// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
 ///
 /// Set ApiKey to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps tab of
 ///   https://cloud.google.com/console
 /// Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 /// </summary>
 internal class Search
 {
   [STAThread]
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Search");
     Console.WriteLine("========================");

     try
     {
       new Search().Run().Wait();
     }
     catch (AggregateException ex)
     {
       foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
       }
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
     Console.ReadKey();
   }

   private async Task Run()
   {
     var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
     {
       ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
       ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
     });

     var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
     searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
     searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

     // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
     var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

     List<string> videos = new List<string>();
     List<string> channels = new List<string>();
     List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

     // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
     // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
     foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
     {
       switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
       {
         case "youtube#video":
           videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
           break;

         case "youtube#channel":
           channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
           break;

         case "youtube#playlist":
           playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
           break;
       }
     }

     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
   }
 }
}
```

Using few online converters, I managed to get this vb.net code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Upload
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
       Try
               New Search.Run().Wait()
           Catch ex As AggregateException

           For Each e In ex.InnerExceptions
               MsgBox("Error: " & e.Message)
           Next
       End Try
   End Sub
   Private Async Function Run() As Task
       Dim youtubeService = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
           .ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
           .ApplicationName = Me.[GetType]().ToString()
       })
       Dim searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet")
       searchListRequest.Q = TextBox1.Text
       searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1
       Dim searchListResponse = Await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync()
       Dim videos As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
       Dim channels As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
       Dim playlists As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

       For Each searchResult In searchListResponse.Items

           videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId))

       Next

       MsgBox(String.Format("Videos:" & vbLf & "{0}" & vbLf, String.Join(vbLf, videos)))
   End Function
End Class
```

I setted a limit on searchListRequest.MaxResults to return me only 1 result, which means I want to get only the first searched video ID and  searchListRequest.Q is connected to a textbox.

In this textbox I'll then write a qwery and I want that once I press the button, a msgbox will appear with the ID of the first searched video..
I'm having 3 errors at debug:

- Syntax error on the line **New Search.Run().Wait()**
- 'Message' is not a member of 'EventArgs'. on the line **MsgBox("Error: " & e.Message)**
- Value of type 'Exception' cannot be converted to 'EventArgs'. on the line  **For Each e In ex.InnerExceptions**

What Am I supposed to fix them? Thanks

edit:
The complete working code is:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Upload
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Await Run()
        Catch ex As AggregateException

            For Each inner In ex.InnerExceptions
                MsgBox("Error: " & inner.Message)
            Next
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Async Function Run() As Task
        Dim youtubeService = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .ApiKey = "your api key ",
            .ApplicationName = Me.[GetType]().ToString()
        })
        Dim searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet")
        searchListRequest.Q = TextBox1.Text
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1
        Dim searchListResponse = Await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync()
        Dim videos As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim channels As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim playlists As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

        For Each searchResult In searchListResponse.Items

            videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId))

        Next

        MsgBox(String.Format("Videos:" & vbLf & "{0}" & vbLf, String.Join(vbLf, videos)))
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You don't have a Search class, just a Run() method. Make your Button.Click handler `async` and `await Run()` (don't use `.Wait()` or `.Result` in WinForms - the example is for a Console app)

Comment: Hei Jimi, thanks I did what you said. I fixed the first issue of sintax error, but the other two are still in there...

Comment: You have `e As EventArgs` in the event handler, don't name another local variable the same way, change `e` to e.g., `For Each inner In ex.InnerExceptions [...] inner.Message`

Comment: That's works like a charm. Just one more thing.. If now I want to add the video I've found to an existing playlist, I sow the endpoint [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/playlists#playlistItems-insert) does the job, but how Am i able to implement it? There is no code sample in there. It just give me a requesto body. Do you think it would be possible to make it work both search a video and add it to a playlist? Thanks

Comment: You have to create a new `PlaylistItemSnippet` object, specify the PlayList ID, build a new `ResourceId` object, specify the Kind and VideoID and your ResourceID, add the RousourceId to the snippet (`[snippet].setResourceId()`? no sure), then `[playlistItem].setSnippet([your snippet])`. Create an insert request (should be `dim request = youtubeService.playlistItems().insert("snippet", [the playlist item])`) and `dim result = request.execute()` -- Anyway, this is a different thing, post another question that includes the working code used to retrieve the video item.

Comment: Hey Jimi, I'll post immediately a new question. Btw, the code to retrieve the video item is exactly what I've been posting,  a part from the issues you fixed :).. I'll update anyway.